# What types of VM-Exception are there?

Tags: solidity

I am aware of the following types (as reported by testrpc/ganache & truffle):

- `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`
- `VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`
- `VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`
- `VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP`

Are there any other types which I am not aware of?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it in truffle source code (file `/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js`):

```
{
    OUT_OF_GAS:"out of gas",
    STACK_UNDERFLOW:"stack underflow",
    STACK_OVERFLOW:"stack overflow",
    INVALID_JUMP:"invalid JUMP",
    INVALID_OPCODE:"invalid opcode",
    REVERT:"revert",
    STATIC_STATE_CHANGE:"static state change"
}
```

Comment: Good find. However, given that truffle is only a test framework, would it be better to find out the list from the source code of a real client (geth or parity)?

Comment: @LinmaoSong: Maybe in the EVM yellow paper.